# "weil" alleine im Satz

Tags: sentence-structure, punctuation, comma, conjunction

> Kant behauptete, man solle aus der Pflicht heraus und nicht nur weil man sonst bestraft wird, handeln.

1. Ist dieser Satz grammatikalisch korrekt? Wenn ja, ist die Kommasetzung korrekt bzw. wie wäre sie korrekt?
2. Wenn dieser Satz nicht grammatikalisch korrekt ist, müsste man ihn in etwa so korrigieren:

> Kant behauptete, man solle aus der Pflicht heraus und nicht nur deswegen, weil man sonst bestraft wird, handeln.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grammatikalisch korrekt ist er. Durch die finale Stellung des Verbs *»handeln«* muss man das darauf bezogene *»man solle aus der Pflicht heraus«* allerdings bis zum Schluss im Kopf behalten, das ermüdet. Darum besser:

> Kant behauptete, man solle aus der Pflicht heraus handeln und nicht
>   nur, weil man sonst bestraft wird.

Gemäß den geltenden [Regeln](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/komma) würde ich die Kommasetzung im ursprünglichen Satz so vornehmen:

> Kant behauptete, man solle aus der Pflicht heraus und nicht nur, weil
>   man sonst bestraft wird, handeln.

Dein Schlusssatz ist korrekt, hat aber ebenfalls das finale *»handeln«* und ist dadurch, dass man *»deswegen«* aussparen könnte, unnötig umständlich.

Comment: grammatisch korrekter wäre natürlich noch Konjunktiv *,weil man sonst bestraft würde.*